# Scala Futures Functional Composition - how to access first result?

Tags: scala

Newbie scala question.

Considering the example in http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html val

```
rateQuote = future {
  connection.getCurrentValue(USD)
}
val purchase = rateQuote map {
  quote => if (isProfitable(quote)) connection.buy(amount, quote)
           else throw new Exception("not profitable")
}
purchase onSuccess {
  case _ => println("Purchased " + amount + " USD")
}
```

How could i access quote variable in purchase onSuccess, eg:

```
purchase onSuccess {
  case _ => println("Purchased " + amount + " USD for quote" + quote)
}
```

I could simply assign it in map to some global variable.. but?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Quote` is the type:

```
purchase onSuccess {
  case quote: Quote => println(s"Purchased  $amount USD for $quote")
  case _ => println("Not a quote, something went wrong")
}
purchase onFailure {
  // failure is a Throwable!
  case failure => println("oops");
}

purchase on Success {
   case quote: Quote => println(s"Purchased $amount USD for $quote")
}
```

Comment: Actually in this particular example you cannot go without type: `case quote => ...`

Comment: Thanks!, one more clarification, what if connection.buy also returned some type? How can i do that with case? Because now if i understand quote case has different scope?

Answer (score 0):

this should also work

```
purchase onSuccess { result =>
    println("Purchased " + amount + " USD")
}
```

while `case` is a nice thing to use for deconstructing complex object such as when working with `case class`, `Option`, `Try`, or `Tuple`, it isn't mandatory especially if the value you want to access is a simple scalar-like value.